# Laravel - Setting Router for the first time

Tags: php, laravel

Im setting my first Laravel project, and Im getting into the first trouble.

Router.php:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});

Route::any('home', function ()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

when I access `http://localhost/laravel/public/home` I get a "Not found" error, even though simple `http://localhost/laravel/public/` works allright. What am i doing wrong? mod_rewrite is enabled and `'index' => ''`.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have a view folder called "home" with a file called "index.php"?

Comment: Have you tried the alternate `.htaccess` as shown here (at the very bottom) http://laravel.com/docs/install

Comment: Yes, file `index.blade.php` exists. The alternative `.htaccess` didnt help either.

Comment: Did you check you do **not** have a home directory within you public directory? And do you have anything set on your `application.url` config?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am about to post a similar question and it would be awesome if you could give come incite.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and was able to answer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488910/issue-with-simple-http-requests-with-laravel-routes-php/15489378#15489378

Comment: I dont have a home directory on my public directory. In the application.php I set up the key and set "index" => "". Emanegux, our error is different. I dont get a "No input file specified" message. I get a "404 not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug found! My VirtualHost had `AllowOverride None`. I changed it to `AllowOverride All` and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

In `application/config/application.php`, try changing your index url to `http://localhost/laravel/public/`.