# Issue with simple HTTP requests with Laravel Routes.php

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel

I am trying to get the most basic functionality to work on Laravel and am having a really hard time. I want the client to be able to send a request in the form of www.mysite.com/laravel/public/this and have the home.index view file returned from the home folder, all of this being determined by routes specified in the laravel/application/routes.php file.

The following function, included in the installation, routes correctly and demonstrates that www.mysite.com/laravel/public works to take the http request from the user and return the correct data

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('home.index');
});
```

But as soon as I change '/' to 'this' and send the request...

```
Route::get('this', function()
{
return View::make('home.index');
});
```

I get "No input file specified." message. How is this happening? I have tried it with localhost and it works fine but I want it to work on my godaddy shared php server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its too simple.

Go to htaccess in public directory and change

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

to

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1508

I cannot believe a mere character has caused me so much frustration

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this will solve my problem too. I'm moving old laravel 3 app to a new server with a complex config and new versions of apache etc. and I was getting really frustrated with the error...

Comment: Turns out, that when I used above rewrite rule, the query strings stopped working - for example pagination didn't work. The correct rewrite for me was `RewriteRule . index.php [L]`